# How to check if an input is equal to a string

Tags: c#, console

I am trying to make a friendly ai, but I need to be able to detect if the input is equal to a string. I tried a lot of things, but none of them worked.

Here is my code so far... ;)

```
namespace Game
{
    public static class Program
    {
        public static string name;
        public static string enteredCommand;
        public static int commanddomath = 1;
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.Title = "Phil";
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;

            Console.WriteLine("                           ");
            Console.WriteLine("             / /        / /");
            Console.WriteLine("             |@|        |@|");
            Console.WriteLine("                --_____--  ");
            Console.WriteLine("                 //////    ");
            Console.WriteLine("                           ");
            

            Console.WriteLine("Hello, my name is Phil");

            Console.WriteLine("What is your name");

            name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, " + name);
           //  Console.WriteLine("What do you want me to do?");
           //  enteredCommand = Console.ReadLine();

           // if (enteredCommand = 1)
           // {

           // }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(enteredCommand == "1")
```

As `Console.ReadLine` returns a string, you will also need to compare it to a string, not an integer

Comment: @Phil: Please be sure to accept this answer since it helped you. You can accept answers by clicking the gray checkmark to the left of the post.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to stick to

```
string.Equals(string1, string2);
```

for comparing strings in the future, since it is **less type strict**. (i.e. you can compare **object obj = "string"** and **string str = "string"** using **.Equals** and you will get **true**, while using **"=="** the result will be **false**.

PS. Don't use it when type safety is necessary.

It also accepts

```
System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase
```

Which ignores casing for strings/objects.

```
if (string.Equals(enteredCommand, "1")) 
{
  //do something
}
```